# Javascript why preventdefault doesn't avoid newline with enter key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why preventdefaut doesn't prevent newline in this example
https://jsfiddle.net/begv2sw1/

```
    let area = document.getElementById("area"); 
    area.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
     if ((event.keyCode === 13)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("submit").click();
     } 
    });
    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = () => {
    alert('submit');
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use input box instead of textarea?

Comment: I tried "keydown" and it worked.

Comment: @VandolphReyes and why not textarea ?

Comment: @atmin why would it be different with keyup ?

Comment: @atmin ok thanks I can use keydown.